# Deploying asp core 2.0 ef website to azure Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

So I have bene trying to publish my website on the azure platform I created a database on azure. And pasted the connectionstring in the database settings on the publish menu .

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.))
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
>
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.))

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and error message. I think the reason for this problem is that the connection string was not modified when you publish your app, it is still the local one.

If you don't remember to choose the checkbox as below, please choose it and try again.

[image]

We can use KuDu to check if we use the correct connection string of Azure Database.

About how to use KUDU, we can refer to: [Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

We can go to site->wwwroot->appsettings.production.json to check if we use the correct connection string as below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer I totally forgot to change the connection string in my app-settings.json

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue the problem was that I forgot to change the connection string in the app settings json file. I also had to use the Microsoft azure migration application to transfer the database over to azure without migration errors